# why None is printed in output??? python

Tags: python

```
import json

file = 'favnum.json'

def save_fav():
    number = input('Type your favourite number: ')
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        num = json.dump(number, f)
        return num

def get_stored_number():
    try:   
        with open(file) as f:
            number_fav = json.load(f)
        
    except FileNotFoundError:
        return None
    else:
        return number_fav

def main_number():
    num = get_stored_number()
    
    if num:
        print('your favourite number is: ')
        print(num)
    
    else:
        print('the number had not saved before\nthus you have to save it')
        numbers = save_fav()
        print('your number is saved')
        print(numbers)

main_number()
```

Output:

```
the number had not saved before
thus you have to save it
Type your favourite number: 3.14
your number is saved
None
```

Comment: `save_fav()` returns None because `json.dump()` returns none.

Comment: i had a similar code but it did not return None

Comment: We can't know about your similar code... Your current code returns `None` because that's what `json.dump` returns. Did you mean to do `return number` in `save_fav`?

Comment: i removed the return number  . i just wrote json.dump(number , f).. then also the same output is coming

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should return number instead of num in the function save_fav()

Answer (score 0):

Because that `json.dump` does not return anything except None and you are saving it in num, and returning num so function returns num too. So return anything meaningful else like even an empty string.

Answer (score 0):

I think your function:

```
def save_fav():
    number = input('Type your favourite number: ')
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        num = json.dump(number, f)
        return num
```

should be this instead:

```
def save_fav():
    number = input('Type your favourite number: ')
    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        json.dump(number, f)
    return number
```

In your version, `json.dump` returns `None`, and so that's what you are returning from the function, and then printing later on.